# Magento checkout after load refresh and redirect to other URL

Tags: checkout

M2.4.6-p2. After redirecting to checout, chekout form is loaded and then in same second its like that page is reloaded to other url https://one.elavonpay.com/aflink.php.. how to find in Magento where is this piece of code to remove it.

M2.4.6-p2 is new installation, from old project there left only database and images... everthing else is brand new....

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong, proper problem is: M2.4.6-p2. After redirecting to checout, chekout form is loaded and then in same second its like that page is reloaded anf form action is set to https://one.elavonpay.com/aflink.php and checkout form is different, just personal data and credit card info... no other details or fields.

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to dump the database and open it in any editor, search for the URL.
That way you can find where the script is, in which table.

Also, check if it is in the admin panel
Content -> Configuration -> Open all stores -> Check Html head (Scripts or Style sheets)
Since here are scrips that are included on all pages